# Simple Javascript changing display data using Jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax

I am learning about AJAX so after watching a youtube video on "How to load in data from a server using AJAX" I copied the code as instructed but when I attempt to use the button to change the data; the data doesnt change.  Can anyone let me know why this isnt working for me.

Here is the HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Ajax Test</title>
    
    <!--<style type="txt/css"></style>-->
<link rel="stylesheet" 
    href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js" 
    integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0=" 
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    
<script> $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#btn").click(function() {
        $("#test").load("newdata.txt", {Name: "Daniel", 
                                        Lastname: "Nielsen"
                                    }, function(){
                                        alert("Hi there!!");
                                    });
    });
    
});
</script>


</head>
<body>
<div id="test">
<p>
This is the first content!    
</p>
</div>
<button id="btn">Click to Change</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Here is the new data that is my change,
newdata.txt

```
<p> This is new data!!</p>
```

I know this is simple but in order for me to understand further, I need to know why code seems to work for others when its not working for me.

Comment: this code refers to TSjava.js in a relative path which means you should first upload TSjava.js in the given address then run the code.

Comment: I deleted that js code TSjava.js... its really nothing on that page anyway.  I get the alert but the data isnt changing.

Answer (score 0):

The answer was that the code would only work while page was on a server since AJAX is server side communication.  I'm sorry to waste anyones time, but I am trying to learn how to display info on my page using AJax methods.

Thank you.